# My GKE pods stoped with error "no command specified: CreateContainerError"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Everything was Ok and nodes were fine for months, but suddenly some pods stopped with an error [image]

I tried to delete pods and nodes but same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below possible solutions to resolve your issue:**

**Solution 1 :**

Check a malformed character in your Dockerfile and cause it to crash.

When you encounter `CreateContainerErro`r is to check that you have a valid ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile used to build your container image. However, if you don’t have access to the Dockerfile, you can configure your pod object by using a valid command in the command attribute of the object.

So workaround is to not specify any `workerConfig` explicitly which makes the workers inherit all configs from the master.

Refer to [Troubleshooting the container runtime](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/container-runtime), similar [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350893/kubernetes-gcp-error-response-from-daemon-no-command-specified-createcontainer), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390812/how-to-fix-kubernetes-create-container-error) & Also check this similar [github link](https://github.com/krustlet/krustlet/issues/238) for more information.

**Solution 2 :**

`Kubectl describe pod podname` command provides detailed information about each of the pods that provide Kubernetes infrastructure. With the help of this you can check for clues, if `Insufficient CPU` follows the solution below.

**The solution is to either:**

1)Upgrade the boot disk: If using a pd-standard disk, it's recommended to upgrade to pd-balanced or pd-ssd.

2)Increase the disk size.

3)Use node pool with machine type with more CPU cores.

See [Adjust worker, scheduler, triggerer and web server scale and performance parameters](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/scale-environments#workloads-configuration) for more information.

If you still have the issue, you can then update the GKE version for your cluster [Manually upgrading the control plane](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrade_cp)to one of the fixed versions.

Also check whether you have updated it in the last year to use the new [kubectl authentication coming in the GKE v1.26 plugin](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke)?

**Solution 3 :**

If you're having a pipeline on GitLab that deploys an image to a GKE cluster: Check the version of the Gitlab runner that handles the jobs of your pipeline .

Because it turns out that every image built through a Gitlab runner running on an old version causes this issue at the container start. Simply deactivate them and only let Gitlab runners running last version in the pool, replay all pipelines.

Check the gitlab CI script using an old docker image like `docker:19.03.5-dind`, update to `docker:dind` helps the kubernetes to start the pod again.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day. It was solution 3, docker image problem, i changed it and it's working fine now.